# Disable ssh auth by keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Usually people try to disable ssh login with password only.
I'm asking about reverse situation.
Does sshd_config allow to disable authentication with keys only?

Comment: The next thing you should look for is Google.

Comment: -1 because plain and simple, there is no good reason to do this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/sshd_config/

```
PubkeyAuthentication
         Specifies whether public key authentication is allowed.  The
         default is ``yes''.  Note that this option applies to protocol
         version 2 only.
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, one more option you may use `AuthenticationMethods`, please refer https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)

Please read doc carefully before apply.